# Rcpp share same roxygen between two functions

Tags: r, rcpp, roxygen2, roxygen, rcpp11

Consider the following functions:

```
//' Provides some stuff AB
//' @param a integer that responsible for stuff A
//' @param b integer that responsible for stuff B
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector foo1(int a, int b)
{
   //some code
}

//' Provides some stuff AC
//' @param a integer that responsible for stuff A
//' @param c integer that responsible for stuff C
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector foo2(int a, int c)
{
   //some code
}
```

Note that parameter **a** description should be the same for foo1 and foo2. I have many functions where **a** parameter description should be provided in the same way. I don't whant to copy-past **a** parameter's description every time I need it for every function separately. Is it possible to specify **a** description ones and apply it to all functions my Rcpp package provides?

Will be very greatfull for help!

Comment: I think that is entirely a `roxygen2` as opposed to `Rcpp` question, and yes, I think I have it seen used -- maybe `@rdname` is all you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Dirk Eddelbuettel I have found the answer:

```
//' @name sharable
//' @rdname sharable
//' @param a integer that responsible for stuff A
//' @export

//' Provides some stuff AB
//' @rdname sharable
//' @param b integer that responsible for stuff B
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector foo1(int a, int b)
{
   //some code
}

//' Provides some stuff AC
//' @rdname sharable
//' @param c integer that responsible for stuff C
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector foo2(int a, int c)
{
   //some code
}
```